# Angular replacewith in directive and mouseenter/mouseleave

Tags: angularjs, directive

My target is pretty simple. There will be an show-overlay directive on images. If you enter mouse, it will wrap with a parent span and append overlay. On mouseleave it will remove the parent span and overlay div.
But for some reason if I use replaceWith on mouseleave it causes to fire the mouseenter unexpectedly multiple times for the next enters.

The directive as is below

```
app.directive('showOverlay', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {

            $element.on('mouseenter', function (e) {
                console.warn('mouseenter');
                $el = $element.wrap("<span class='img'></div>")
              $el = $el.parent().append("<div  ng-mouseleave='cancelEditMode($event)' class='overlay'></div>");
                $element.parent().addClass("hover");
              var inputElem = $element.parent();
              $compile(inputElem)($scope);
            });

            $scope.cancelEditMode = function(e) {
                $element.parent().replaceWith($element);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

From the above code, looks like the replacewith causes $element to have multiple mouseenter event.
jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/979/

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest this more efficient approach (using CSS `:hover` instead of JS) to achieve the same thing:

**JS**

```
app.directive('showOverlay', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
            $el = $element.wrap("<span class='img hover'></div>")
            $el = $el.parent().append("<div class='overlay'></div>");
        }
    };
});
```

**additional CSS**

```
.img .overlay {
  display: none;
}
.img:hover .overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

**jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/0aj5osw0/

Comment: Thanks elfan, but the problem is that I cannot leave the dom with some extra element, which was not originally there. What I mean, I must remove the extra elements like span, orverlay div at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

**html code**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
 <overlay   class='overlay'></overlay>
 <img show-overlay src="http://www.queness.com/resources/images/png/apple_raw.png" />
</div>
```

**javascirpt**

```
app.directive('showOverlay', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
       $element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
             angular.element('overlay').addClass('showContent')
        })  
        angular.element('overlay').bind('mouseleave', function() {
             angular.element('overlay').removeClass('showContent')
        })

    }
 };
});
```

**css**

```
 [editable]:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: dotted thin rgba(0, 191, 255, 0.5);
}

.img {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;

}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  width:400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color:red;
  display: none;
}
.showContent{
  display: block;
   z-index: 20;

}
.hideContent{
  display: none;
  z-index: 0;

}
```

Comment: any jsfiddle link please?

Comment: just copy and past my code into your project it's works fine.

Comment: Thanks but it uses a fixed sized overlay which I don't want

Comment: ok fine into mouseenter action you can read the parent height and width then just apply the height and with on overlay.

Comment: Your solution will work if there is only image in the dom, nothing else